# aggregate per variable over which sums are calculated in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have some time data

```
library(data.table); library(lubridate); set.seed(42)
dat <- rbind(data.table(time=as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 08:00:00") + round(runif(10,60,1e4)), val=runif(10),group=1)[order(time), id:=seq_len(.N)],
             data.table(time=as.POSIXct("2019-02-01 18:00:00") + round(runif(10,60,1e4)), val=runif(10),group=2)[order(time), id:=seq_len(.N)])
> dat[order(group,id)]
                   time         val group id
 1: 2019-01-01 08:23:19 0.117487362     1  1
 2: 2019-01-01 08:48:24 0.934672247     1  2
 3: 2019-01-01 09:27:00 0.940014523     1  3
 4: 2019-01-01 09:47:19 0.462292823     1  4
 5: 2019-01-01 09:49:51 0.474997082     1  5
 6: 2019-01-01 09:57:48 0.560332746     1  6
 7: 2019-01-01 10:03:02 0.978226428     1  7
 8: 2019-01-01 10:18:35 0.255428824     1  8
 9: 2019-01-01 10:32:33 0.457741776     1  9
10: 2019-01-01 10:36:15 0.719112252     1 10
11: 2019-02-01 18:14:39 0.003948339     2  1
12: 2019-02-01 18:23:59 0.811055141     2  2
13: 2019-02-01 19:05:39 0.007334147     2  3
14: 2019-02-01 19:15:03 0.906601408     2  4
15: 2019-02-01 19:26:11 0.832916080     2  5
16: 2019-02-01 20:19:30 0.611778643     2  6
17: 2019-02-01 20:30:46 0.737595618     2  7
18: 2019-02-01 20:31:03 0.207658973     2  8
19: 2019-02-01 20:37:50 0.685169729     2  9
20: 2019-02-01 20:44:50 0.388108283     2 10
```

and I would like to calculate the sum of `val` during the following hour for each value of `time`. For example, for ID 1, this would be the sum of `val` for IDs 1 and 2 (because time for ID 3 is more than one hour after ID 1), for ID 2, the sum of `val` for IDs 2 to 4, and so forth. This yields the desired output (for group 1 only)

```
> res
                   time       val id     new1     new2
 1: 2019-01-01 08:23:19 0.1174874  1 1.052160 1.052160
 2: 2019-01-01 08:48:24 0.9346722  2 2.336979 2.336979
 3: 2019-01-01 09:27:00 0.9400145  3 3.671292 3.671292
 4: 2019-01-01 09:47:19 0.4622928  4 3.908132 3.908132
 5: 2019-01-01 09:49:51 0.4749971  5 3.445839       NA
 6: 2019-01-01 09:57:48 0.5603327  6 2.970842       NA
 7: 2019-01-01 10:03:02 0.9782264  7 2.410509       NA
 8: 2019-01-01 10:18:35 0.2554288  8 1.432283       NA
 9: 2019-01-01 10:32:33 0.4577418  9 1.176854       NA
10: 2019-01-01 10:36:15 0.7191123 10 0.719112       NA
```

where two behaviors at the end are possible:

1. where the sequence is treated as is;
2. where sums are only calculated until there is not id for which there is an id with `time` at least an hour later, and all others are set NA (preferred).

I suspect that solving this requires me to subset within `j` but this is a problem I frequently run into and can't solve. I have not yet understood the general approach to this.

Comment: Not clear though.  If you  aree summing for the hour '08', why is 6th observation used `09`

Comment: because it's not about clock hours but `time` plus one hour. So, all `ids` are included for which `time < time[i] + 3600`.

Comment: The data posted previously was inconsistent with the seed. Apologies for that. Should be correct now.

Comment: I see, great! If you have a quick way to get to `sum2`, that would be much appreciated, also to make the post complete in case it is useful to others later.

Comment: Yes, if all subsequent times are less than an hour after the current time, this would be an `NA` because there is no full hour after current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a loop with join

```
dat1 <- dat[order(id)]
out <- rbindlist(lapply(dat1$id, function(i) {
      d1 <- dat1[seq_len(.N) >= match(i, id)]
      d1[d1[, .(time = time %m+% hours(1))], .(time1 = time, val, new1 = sum(val)),
         on = .(time <= time), by = .EACHI][1]
      }))[, time := NULL][]
setnames(out, 1, "time")
out[time < time[2]   %m+% hours(1), new2 := new1]
out
#                   time       val      new1     new2
# 1: 2019-01-01 08:23:19 0.1174874 1.0521596 1.052160
# 2: 2019-01-01 08:48:24 0.9346722 2.3369796 2.336980
# 3: 2019-01-01 09:27:00 0.9400145 3.6712924 3.671292
# 4: 2019-01-01 09:47:19 0.4622928 3.9081319 3.908132
# 5: 2019-01-01 09:49:51 0.4749971 3.4458391       NA
# 6: 2019-01-01 09:57:48 0.5603327 2.9708420       NA
# 7: 2019-01-01 10:03:02 0.9782264 2.4105093       NA
# 8: 2019-01-01 10:18:35 0.2554288 1.4322829       NA
# 9: 2019-01-01 10:32:33 0.4577418 1.1768540       NA
#10: 2019-01-01 10:36:15 0.7191123 0.7191123       NA
```

#### Update

For the new data, we can `split` by group and apply the same method

```
f1 <- function(data) {
              lst1 <- split(data, data[["group"]])
              rbindlist(lapply(lst1, function(.dat) {
                out <- rbindlist(lapply(.dat$id, function(i) {
                      d1 <- .dat[seq_len(.N) >= match(i, id)]
                      d1[d1[, .(time = time %m+% hours(1))], .(time1 = time, val, new1 = sum(val)),
                         on = .(time <= time), by = .EACHI][1]
                      }))[, time := NULL][]
                setnames(out, 1, "time")

                out[time[.N]-time > hours(1), new2 := new1][] 
              })
              )}

 f1(dat1)
 #                  time         val      new1      new2
 #1: 2019-01-01 08:23:19 0.117487362 1.0521596 1.0521596
 #2: 2019-01-01 08:48:24 0.934672247 2.3369796 2.3369796
 #3: 2019-01-01 09:27:00 0.940014523 3.6712924 3.6712924
 #4: 2019-01-01 09:47:19 0.462292823 3.9081319 3.9081319
 #5: 2019-01-01 09:49:51 0.474997082 3.4458391        NA
 #6: 2019-01-01 09:57:48 0.560332746 2.9708420        NA
 #7: 2019-01-01 10:03:02 0.978226428 2.4105093        NA
 #8: 2019-01-01 10:18:35 0.255428824 1.4322829        NA
 #9: 2019-01-01 10:32:33 0.457741776 1.1768540        NA
#10: 2019-01-01 10:36:15 0.719112252 0.7191123        NA
#11: 2019-02-01 18:14:39 0.003948339 0.8223376 0.8223376
#12: 2019-02-01 18:23:59 0.811055141 1.7249907 1.7249907
#13: 2019-02-01 19:05:39 0.007334147 1.7468516 1.7468516
#14: 2019-02-01 19:15:03 0.906601408 1.7395175 1.7395175
#15: 2019-02-01 19:26:11 0.832916080 1.4446947        NA
#16: 2019-02-01 20:19:30 0.611778643 2.6303112        NA
#17: 2019-02-01 20:30:46 0.737595618 2.0185326        NA
#18: 2019-02-01 20:31:03 0.207658973 1.2809370        NA
#19: 2019-02-01 20:37:50 0.685169729 1.0732780        NA
#20: 2019-02-01 20:44:50 0.388108283 0.3881083        NA
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how the solution works to see where I could add the grouping variable mentioned in the post. Is this possible at all?

Comment: @bumblebee  If it needs to have a grouping column, it woould be within `on`

Comment: Only adding it to `on` yields the error that `group` is not found in `i`
. Perhaps it is easiest to see it in action. I have added a grouping variable to the post (somewhat complicated to keep the data for group 1 the same). Could you update the solution to show how this works?

Comment: I noticed, however, that there is a subtle error in `new2`: If there is a break longer than one hour between subsequent `ids`, it produces `NA`. This should not be the case. The cutoff should not be "no ID within the next hour" but "all subsequent IDs less than one hour" after current time.

Comment: @bumblebee IN that case, after the `split`, you can `order` by the 'time' column and then apply the function

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I believe the error is in `out[time < time[2] %m+% hours(1), new2 := new1][]`. Can this be changed such that `new2` is calculated for all IDs for which the final ID of each group is more than one hour later?

Comment: @bumblebee  WIth the example, i am not getting the error though

Comment: Correct, because in the example, there is no gap between ids larger than 1 hour. To get an example, use `dat <- dat[id!=2]`. Now there is a gap longer than 1 hour between IDs 1 and 3 and I would think it produces `NA` for ID 1.

Comment: do you think, this is at all possible within `data.table`?

Comment: @bumblebee  It could be possible, but needs some time to think about.  In the mean time, let's see if somebody comes up with a solution

Comment: no worries. I came up with a solution and edited it into your answers. Thanks!

Comment: I do have one more question, though. How would I modify the solution to calculate averages of `val` for the previous hour?

Comment: @bumblebee Here, we are looping over each id `lapply(.dat$id,`  and then create a subset of data based on the id,  `d1 <- .dat[seq_len(.N) >= match(i, id)]`, non-equi join with the data created with 1 hour added `d1[, .(time = time %m+% hours(1))]`  From this output, do you need to take a `lag` for each hour and calculate it?